# Read data from thingspeak using python using urllib library

Tags: json, python-2.7, iot

I wanted to read current data from thingspeak website 
I used urllib library to get data using read url of the channel

i used python code

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data=urllib.urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/my_channel_no/feeds.json? 
results=2")
print data.read()
select=repr(data.read())
print select
sel=select[20:]
print sel


https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/my_channel_no/feeds.json?results=2
```

I get this result from the query

```
'{"channel{"id":my_channel_no,"name":"voltage","latitude":"0.0","longitude":"0.0 ","field1":"Field Label 1","field2":"Field Label 2","created_at":"2018-04-05T16:33:14Z","updated_at":"2018-04-09T15:39:43Z","last_entry_id":108},"feeds":[{"created_at":"2018-04-09T15:38:42Z","entry_id":107,"field1":"20.00","field2":"40.00"},{"created_at":"2018-04-09T15:39:44Z","entry_id":108,"field1":"20.00","field2":"40.00"}]}'
```

But when this line was executed

```
select=repr(data.read())
```

the result was

```
"''"
```

And

```
sel=select[20:]
```

Output

```
''
```

This is used to reduce the length of the query 
 Can anyone give me sense of direction whats happening and solution for this selection of field value is the goal.